# Edit html text value using directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my app, I'm using some variable which contain a code instead of the value itself. This code matches one field of an array which items contain the code with the matching value. What I could do to display the name is a loop to find the value based on the code. But as my app has a lot of these, I would need to do it for each value.

Here is the array:

```
[{code: 'PN', name: 'Panasonic'}, {code: 'SN', name: 'Sony'}]
```

Therefore, I thought using an attribute would be much better and cleaner. I would like to put the following jade: `div(json-array={{televisions}}) {{ code }}` and change the displayed `code` with `televisions[X].name`. The problem is that I'm not so familiar with directives.

I tried to use the link function to catch the value (code) and the binded variable array ({{televisions}}) but I encountered two problems:

- How can I modify the div value without modifying the binded variable (code)?
- How do I get the array (televisions) within my directive?

Comment: I don't think a directive is appropriate here. Why don't you give a little more context (and code). This sounds more like an `ngRepeat` situation (but even if not, a directive doesn't seem appropriate).

Comment: ng-repeat is definitely not appropriate for that... directives are used to reformat or modify the html page. What I need to do is exactly that, reformat the text. I can't really add code (except the directive I tried to write...) because currently I'm trying to figure out how to do that. Do you want to see what I tried to do?

Comment: Are you only displaying a single `div` with tv.code ? How is the `tv` object determined ?

Comment: yes, I'm only displaying a single div. tv is just a simple variable. Instead of tv.code, I should have write code (just edited...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still wouldn't use a directive for that. It is a simple presentation issue and can be easily (and declaratively) handled in the view (yet the question lacks all necessary info in order to provide the most appropriate solution).

```
<div>{{getTelevisionName(tv.code)}}</div>

$scope.getTelevisionName = function (code) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.televisions.length; i++) {
        var tv = $scope.televisions[i];
        if (tv.code === code) return tv.name;
    }
    return '';
};
```

Comment: OK, this answer is already in my question. What would you do if you had hundreds of these variables in different controllers? Would you still write hundred times these loops?

Comment: As I've been trying to tell you (for quite some time) the provided info is not sufficient for deciding upon the best approach. I might create a custom filter, change the function so it takes the array as an argument (and probably move it into a 'Utils' service for reusability, I might assign the tvName to a variable so I don't have to execute the loops at every $digest cycle or do something completely different based on the exact requirements and constraints. (I would most probably go for the filter though, unless you have huge arrays.)

Comment: Filter is a great idea! Works fantastic and very neat!